# Route page without ID - How to use another field?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am trying to access a specific route with a specific field in my model.

Example:
www.myPage.com/wedding/couple1
www.myPage.com/wedding/couple2

All examples that I found in Ember's community use ID, but I am trying to use another one (which I will make sure to be unique).

My route config:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('create-wedding');
  this.route('weddings');
  this.route('wedding', { path: 'wedding/:pageName' });
});
```

My link to the route:

```
{{#link-to 'wedding' wedding.pageName}}Access{{/link-to}}
```

Try to get the record:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.query('wedding', { orderBy: 'pageName', equalTo: params.pageName });
}
```

But, how to get the record for the specific param "pageName" in my Route model? And how to get the same record when the user access the page directly from the URL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your non-id field is really, truly unique (i.e. enforced uniqueness on the back end), you can use it as your front end id by writing a custom serializer.

```
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'other_unique_key'
});
```

If you are using a REST back end, just swap out `DS.JSONSerializer` for `DS.RESTSerializer` in the code above.

This would allow you to closely follow Ember's conventions for record handling by id. You can read more about authoring custom serializers [here in the Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/current/models/customizing-serializers/).

Another alternative is to use Query Parameters. In that case, your URL would look more like `http://example.com/weddings?wedding=romeojuliet`

Read more about Query Parameters and accessing their values [here in the Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/current/routing/query-params/).

Comment: I am using Firebase as my Database. How I do configure my serializer with Rest (if I am not wrong, Firebase use Rest).

Comment: Easy, change the code above to be RESTSerializer instead of JSONSerializer. And have a read through https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTSerializer/properties/primaryKey?anchor=primaryKey

Comment: When I made the changes, I got the error: Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
 * One or more of the following keys must be present: "data", "errors", "meta".

Comment: My guess is that your requests are not hitting your custom serializer. Instead they are hitting the default application serializer (which is JSONAPI). What is your model name and the name of your serializer? In the end, to use REST you need a serializer that matches your model name, a serializer named application, and an adapter named application. The "application" files do the JSONAPI override. They should specify that they use REST, and don't necessarily need anything else in them.

Comment: I have changed the implementation to REST and start working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great to hear! I'll update my answer with some of the details we chatted about. Good luck with your project :D

Answer (score 0):

More details can be found here. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/models/finding-records/

For this line to work `return this.store.query('wedding', { orderBy: 'pageName', equalTo: params.pageName });`

You'll need to setup filters on your API that will utilize those params.

You can also serialize a new ID, or set up the API to consume a slug instead of an ID. In which case you could do a direct find like this. `return this.get('store').findRecord('wedding', params.pageParam)`

Technically you should use queryRecord instead of query in the case of a single record.

And if it is a single record, what is the purpose of orderBy?

> And how do I get the same record when the user access the page directly from the URL?

Because you have this in your router. `this.route('wedding', { path: 'wedding/:pageName' });`

You are already setup to access it directly in your url as domainname/wedding/pagename